# Call function with variable as paramenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to call the function *fill()* with a variable as parameter. Everytime *next()* is called, the number of the variable should increase.
So first, *fill( q1 )* is called, then *fill( q2 )* and so on. But apparently, you can't use variables as parameters. Any ideas?

```
var q1 = [2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"];
var q2 = [2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"];

var fill = function( data ) {
    $( "#number" ).html( data[1]);
    $( "#cat" ).html( data[2]);
    $( "#ques span" ).html( data[3]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).html( data[4]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).html( data[5]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).html( data[6]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).html( data[7]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(" + data[0] + ") button" ).attr( "data-state",     "correct" );
                }   
var count = 1;
function next() { 
    fill( "q" + count );
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Why not? Of course you can. Could you show more code, like the fill function?

Comment: Oh, I get it. q1 and q2 are variables? So you can use `fill( eval("q"+count) )`.

Comment: Or without evil eval  `fill( window["q"+count] )` since q1 and 2 are in global scope. A better idea would be to have an an array of arrays: `var q = [ [2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"],[2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"]];`

Comment: Or, alternatively, have the q arrays in an object to avoid using `eval`. Like `fill(obj['q' + count])` - http://jsfiddle.net/dtvjzf47/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think a better approach is to make a multi-dimensional array `q`, in stead of `q1` and `q2` etc.

```
var q = [];
q[0] = [2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"];
q[1] = [2, "ff", "dd", "ss", "hh"];

var fill = function( data ) {
    $( "#number" ).html( data[1]);
    $( "#cat" ).html( data[2]);
    $( "#ques span" ).html( data[3]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(1) button" ).html( data[4]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(2) button" ).html( data[5]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(3) button" ).html( data[6]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(4) button" ).html( data[7]);
    $( "#answ .answ:nth-child(" + data[0] + ") button" ).attr( "data-state", "correct" );
                }   
var count = 0;
function next() { 
    fill( q[count] );
    count++;
}
```

This way, you could also check that you're not passing `undefined` to `fill()`:

```
function next() {
    if (count < q.length) {
        fill( q[count] );
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `fill( "q"+count )`, the function will receive "q1" as a string.

If you want to pass the actual value of q1, you can use `fill( eval("q"+count) )`

Comment: Why have I been downvoted, as this is exactly what the OP wants, and they told me in comments that it was right??

Comment: Perhaps it is not always enough to answer OPs question but to answer and educate. `eval` is frowned upon in this community and is almost always avoidable